# Error when i create a database, it shows without any folders

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010

When I create a DB in my solution, for any reason it creates empty (with no folders inside, like tables, or Store Procedures).

I try to make the standard procedure to create it (Data>Add New Data Source>Database>DataSource>New Connection>(Data Sourse: MS SQL Server Database File (Sql Client) and a new database), and creates an empy DB, but it never create the folders. I add some screenshots to explain it better https://prnt.sc/o1x1r1

Comment: I think you mixed mysql and ms sql server up.

Comment: What can i do then?